# CMIS Alfresco - updating a document mime type and file extension name programmatically

Tags: java, alfresco, mime-types, cmis

I have a few documents that were originally uploaded as .doc files with the mimetype of Microsoft Word (application/msword) to alfresco share.

Now I've been able to successfully change the documents extension and update its mime type property to Microsoft Word 2007 (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document).

But, when the file is downloaded and opened with microsoft word, it throws an error saying that the file format doesn't match the extension.

I thought I was doing it correctly but apparently not. 
Here is the part of the code that's supposed to handle the mime type conversion.

```
Map<String, Object> updateProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

updateProperties.put("cmis:name", changeName);
updateProperties.put("cmis:contentStreamFileName", changeName);
document.updateProperties(updateProperties);

ContentStream contentStream = document.getContentStream();
InputStream stream = contentStream.getStream();
ContentStream cs1 = session.getObjectFactory().createContentStream(changeName, docLength, MimeTypes.getMIMEType("docx"), stream);

document.setContentStream(cs1, true);
```

The exact error I am receiving when opening the document in microsoft word is:

**"Word cannot open the file because the file format does not match the file extension"**

I'm not sure how to change the the actual file format of the document during the update. It appears that this solution is not doing it for me. Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: Out of interest, if you use the Alfresco Share interface, got to Edit Properties, and change both the Filename and the Mime Type there, does Word then open the file without error?

Comment: I've tried that as well. Same problem.

Comment: If you download the file to your local machine, rename the extension, then open, does that work ok? (My hunch is it won't as I think you've got a broken file...)

Comment: It won't open on my local machine either, because the file was changed to .docx in alfresco. Changing it back to .doc works again.

Comment: Changing it back to .doc and downloading again works so the file is not corrupt. I think that changing the mime type in alfresco edit properties is simply a metadata change. I was hoping it would change the file format of the actual document itself but that doesn't appear to be the case. I may need to use the output of ContentStream contentStream = document.getContentStream(); and change the stream to .docx before executing the update using some 3rd party java document conversion library.

Comment: Oh, hang on! I thought your users had uploaded it wrong and you were fixing! If you really want to change the overall file type, you need to use a `ContentTransformer` to have the format changed

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the hint. I found this: content.transformer.OpenOffice.extensions.*.docx.supported=false from https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/subsystems/Transformers/default/transformers.properties and, https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/valid-transformations.html   Does that mean that it is not possible to transform to docx atfter all?